# How do I deal with an error message installing Ubuntu from DVD on an old machine?

Tags: system-installation

I have an old Win XP PC that I wiped the drive on (thoroughly).  I downloaded Ubuntu on another PC and copied it onto a DVD.  When I try to boot on the old XP PC from the Ubuntu files on the DVD I get an error message, something like the boot failed... duh.  I selected the boot device after selecting the F10 boot option when I power up the old PC.  Still, the same error message.  If you can help, please keep it simple.  I am only an intermediate user.

Comment: Did you just copy the .iso file onto the DVD? You need to write a DVD image, which is different. For help, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto).

Answer (score 2):

You don't just *copy* an ISO file *or* it's contents to a CD/DVD, as it contains a complete file system, with a boot sector, that's why it's called a *CD image*.

**Note:** If your computer is not *ancient*, it should be able to boot from an USB stick, which is often a better alternative to CD/DVD, as it's faster and more flexible, since you can re-format it later.

Please see [this article](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) on creating a bootable USB stick or [this article](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu) on burning a DVD on Ubuntu.

If you only have Windows at the moment, [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) is how to burn a DVD and [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) is the USB stick guide.

**Tip:** you might want to consider [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net) instead of Ubuntu for your old hardware. They are fully functional, but lightweight compared to Ubuntu in terms of RAM and CPU usage.